# DNS UDP Socket write() issue

Tags: c, sockets, dns, udp

I am trying to send a DNS header and question to a UDP socket. I have already called the following command to establish the connection: `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`, `inet_aton(temp, &servAddr.sin_addr)` using port 53, and `connect(sock, (const sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr))`.

The problem I am having is writing the message that includes the header and the question of the DNS query. So far, my DNS header struct looks like this:

```
struct DNS_Header {
            uint16_t id;
            struct {
                uint8_t rd: 1;      // recursion desired
                uint8_t tc: 1;      // message was truncated
                uint8_t aa: 1;      // authoritative answer
                uint8_t opcode: 4;  // query type
                // 0 a standard query (QUERY); 1 an inverse query (IQUERY);
                // 2 a server status request (STATUS);
                // 3 - 15 reserved for futre use
                uint8_t qr: 1;      // query(0) or response (1)

                uint8_t rcode: 4;   // response code
                // 0: No error condition; 1:Format error; 2:Server failure;
                // 3: Name Error (authoritative server, name doesn't exist)
                // 4: Not implemented; 5: Refused
                uint8_t z: 3;       // reserved for future use. Must be zero
                uint8_t ra: 1;      // recursion
                } flags;
            uint16_t gdcount;
            uint16_t ancount;
            uint16_t nscount;
            uint16_t arcount;
        };
```

I create the DNS query header :

```
   packetHeader.id = htons(1337);   
    packetHeader.flags.rd = 0;          
    packetHeader.flags.tc = 0;          
    packetHeader.flags.aa = 0;          
    packetHeader.flags.opcode = htons(0);       
    packetHeader.flags.qr = 0;          
    packetHeader.flags.rcode = htons(0);    
    packetHeader.flags.z = htons(0);        
    packetHeader.flags.ra = 0;          
    packetHeader.gdcount = htons(1);        
    packetHeader.ancount = htons(0);        
    packetHeader.nscount = htons(0);        
    packetHeader.arcount = htons(0);
```

I am aware I need to change the hostname to the label/data format for the name portion of DNS question. I have done it this way:

```
static const char* const hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    hostname.push_back(' ');
    int len = hostname.length();

    int segCount = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> storage;
    std::string temp = "";

    for (int i  = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (hostname[i] == '.' || hostname[i] == ' ') {
            storage.push_back(std::to_string(0));
            storage.push_back(std::to_string(segCount));
            storage.push_back(temp);
            // reset
            segCount = 0;
            temp = "";
            continue;
        }
        const unsigned char c = hostname[i];
        std::cout << c << " : " << hex[c >> 4] << " " << hex[c & 15] << std::endl;
        temp.push_back(hex[c >> 4]);
        temp.push_back(hex[c & 15]);
        segCount ++;
        continue;
    }

    storage.push_back(std::to_string(0));
    storage.push_back(std::to_string(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < storage.size(); i++) { qname_labelFormat.append(storage[i]); }

    std::cout << "The hex representation of qname TOTAL: " << qname_labelFormat << std::endl
```

I bring everything together for the DNS Query Question using a DNS_Question struct. This struct does not include the DNS Query Question name. I am storing the name in the variable: `qname_lableFormat`. View the DNS Query Question struct below:

```
struct DNS_Question {
            uint16_t qtype;
            uint16_t qclass;
        };
```

To populate the struct DNS_Question, I have done it this way:

```
   int queryTypeNum = 0;

    if (queryType == "A")     { queryTypeNum = 1;  }
    if (queryType == "NS")    { queryTypeNum = 2;  }
    if (queryType == "CNAME") { queryTypeNum = 5;  }
    if (queryType == "SOA")   { queryTypeNum = 6;  }
    if (queryType == "WKS")   { queryTypeNum = 11; }
    if (queryType == "PTR")   { queryTypeNum = 12; }
    if (queryType == "MX")    { queryTypeNum = 15; }
    if (queryType == "SRV")   { queryTypeNum = 33; }
    if (queryType == "AAAA")  { queryTypeNum = 28; }
    if (queryType == "")      { queryTypeNum = 1;  }

    packetQuestion.qtype = htons(queryTypeNum);
    std::cout << "QType value set to: " << queryTypeNum << std::endl;
    packetQuestion.qclass = htons(1);
```

After I have done all of that, I use the socket `write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);` I believe this is where my error is occurring. No error message is reported but when I call the `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` command, nothing is being received. My write command is below.

```
int size = sizeof(struct DNS_Header);
    size += sizeof(struct DNS_Question);
    char *message [size];
    int totalSize = 0;
    int stringSize = qname_labelFormat.length() + 1;
    char* temp = {0};
    temp = (char*)qname_labelFormat.c_str();

    std::memcpy(message, (struct DNS_Header*)&packetHeader, sizeof(packetHeader));
    totalSize = sizeof(struct DNS_Header);

    std::memcpy(message + totalSize, (char*)temp, sizeof(qname_labelFormat));
    totalSize += sizeof(qname_labelFormat);

    std::memcpy(message + totalSize, (struct DNS_Question*)&packetQuestion, sizeof(packetQuestion));
    totalSize += sizeof(packetQuestion);

    int bytesSent = 0;
    if ((bytesSent = write(sock, message, totalSize)) < 0) {
        logger->printLog ("write Failed");
        std::string error = strerror(errno);
        logger->printLog(error);
    }
    else {
        logger->printLog ("write was successful");
}
```

If someone is able to help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Copy/paste error? `uint8_t rcode: 4connect(sock, (const sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)); `

Comment: You don't show it, but are you checking for an `fd` of `-1` on call to `socket`?

Comment: I edited the error with the `uint8_t rcode: 4connect(sock, (const sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)); `. Also, I am checking if `socket` returns -1. I did not include it above because it was not the focus of my question.

Comment: You should either write the packet to a file and provide the hexdump here or catch it from the wire with tcpdump or wireshark. The problem is probably easy to spot there

Comment: Why would I use a tcp dump if I am send messages via UDP?

Comment: @MonaWade there is a tool called tcpdump, which will also dump UDP packets if you ask it nicely

Comment: I have changed the way I send the DNS Query Name because I think that is the source of the problem. It is still bot working though.

Comment: Again: it is a lot harder to stare at the code and trying to see the error than to simply examine the resulting packet and look, what is wrong with it.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve] by focusing on the error case you have, and also did you try to contact other nameservers?